# How to connect Azure Data factory to Salesforce Commerce Cloud?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-connect, salesforce-commerce-cloud

is there a way to connect to  Azure Data factory  to Salesforce Commerce Cloud ?
In Data Factory the I only see connectors to Salesforce Service & Marketing Cloud

if it's possible I'll appreciate it if someone could show me an example
Thank you !

Comment: Hi @Ben, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, from the Azure [Data Factory connector overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview), we can know that  Salesforce Commerce Cloud is not supported.

The only way is that you must achieve that in code level. Then call the [Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity), [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-python) or [Notebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-notebook) active to run it in Data Factory.

There isn't an exist code example we can provide for you. You need design it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

we may infer from the overview of the Azure Data Factory connector (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview) that Salesforce Commerce Cloud is not supported. You can only accomplish that at the code level. In order to run the Function, Python, or Notebook in Data Factory, use the appropriate function. We are unable to give you an existing code example. You must create it on your own.